# How can I get my JS code to store multiple entries from a form through adding/removing fields?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
(function($) {
  "use strict";

  var itemTemplate = $('.input_fields_wrap'),
    editArea = $('.edit-area'),
    itemNumber = 1;

  $(document).on('click', '.edit-area .add', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var item = itemTemplate.clone();

    $(item).find("input[type=text]", "input[type=textarea]", "input[type=number]").removeAttr(0).val('');

    item.find('[partNum]').attr('partNum', function() {
      return $(this).attr('partNum') + '_' + itemNumber;
    });

    ++itemNumber;
    item.appendTo(editArea);
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.edit-area .rem', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var total_fields = itemTemplate[0].childNodes.length;

    if (total_fields > 1) {
      editArea.children('.input_fields_wrap').last().remove();
    }
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.edit-area .del', function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target),
      row = target.closest('.input_fields_wrap');
    row.remove();
  });
}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product_titles">
  <h5 class="titles">Item/Part Number</h5>
  <h5 class="titles">Product Description</h5>
  <h5 class="titles">Quantity</h5>

  <div class="edit-area">
    <button type="button" class="rem">-</button>
    <button type="button" class="add">+</button>
    <br><br>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <label for="contactFormPartNumber" class="hidden-label">{{ 'contact.form.part_number' | t }}</label>
  <div class="formfield"><input type="text" id="contactFormPartNumber" name="contact[{{ 'contact.form.part_number' | t }}]" placeholder="{{ 'contact.form.part_number' | t }} *" required="required"></div>
  <div class="formfield"><input type="text" name="description" placeholder="Product Description"></div>
  <div class="formfield"><input type="number" id="contactQuantity" name="contact[{{ 'contact.form.quantity' | t }}]" value="0" min="0" required="required"></div>
</div>
```

Okay so the problem I have been facing is that every time a new field is created it lets the user type the data but doesn't store it anywhere. I think using arrays might work but I'm not quite sure how I'm supposed to integrate that in my code. Also a weird thing that happens when I create a new field using the buttons is it pushes my first field down but after that the next fields after the second one somehow sandwich between field 1 and 2. I don't quite know why that happens. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is `{{ 'contact.form.part_number' | t }}` supposed to do?

Comment: Ah my bad. So this is basically a .liquid file which just references the .json file to get the values for the name in this case. I’m actually coding this in Shopify for my online store and its a bit confusing working with an already built theme which is why I’m kind of stuck too. Hope it makes sense.